# Jenkins does not trigger build after being poked by GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins

I'm trying to integrate Jenkins with a private repository on GitHub.

I have a Multibranch Pipeline job configured with github's SSH URL: git@github.com:user/repo.git. The GitHub plugin is also installed. On GitHub I added the webhook per-plugin documentation.

Now, whenever a change is pushed to the repo Jenkins logs the event, but not start a build.

My best guess is that it happens due to URL mismatch: the job has SSH url, but github seems to send HTTP URL (http://github.com/user/repo). I do not know how to verify or address it.

Comment: The URL is right. I believe the webhook is wrongly registered. Or no action is registered on commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem by installing the Git Branch Source Plugin and setting up the GitHub source in the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

First check you are able to access git repo from command line like below,

```
ssh git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

If it returns "Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address" . Then its fine else check for ssh key added in git.

If above step is correct then proceed to below task

in project url under Github Project in job config give htttp url ( ex : http://github.com/user/repo ).

in repository url under Source Code Management give git url ( ex : git@github.com:user/repo.git ).

For detailed info 
https://medium.com/@marc_best/trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-a-github-push-b922468ef1ae

Comment: When starting the job manually it can clone the repo. The only source type I see is Git and it can only accept "Project Repository". In general Multibranch Job configuration looks very different from the screenshots on medium.

Comment: then you can specify branch in "repository url under Source Code Management" under advance section defaults it point to master.
Also check the jenkins url is correctly configured in git and your jenkins url and port should be accessible outside world.

Comment: Jenkins does receive events (I can see them in the log). I do not see the Source Code Management pane in Multibranch Job's configuration. There is such pane when you see configuration of a specific branch, but it doesn't seem to be editable (there is no save or apply button).

Comment: ok found one linke with test jenkinsfile script , might be helpfull
https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/
optionally
https://gist.github.com/misterbrownlee/3708738

Comment: Yup, tried that. But I just cannot find where I could specify project URL in a multibranch pipeline job.